# Alternate of Deprecated Nuget.Core in .NET6

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-6.0

Alternate of Deprecated Nuget.Core in .NET6

As nuget.core is now deprecated, is there any other way to download and install the nugets at runtime, in .NET6?

I am using Baget as a nuget feed and want to install the packages at runtime for my project. But as the Nuget.Core is deprecated, i am not able to install my own nuget packages.

Here is the code I was working on:

```
void getPackageByNameAndVersion(string packageID, string version)
        {
            IPackageRepository repo =
                    PackageRepositoryFactory.Default
                          .CreateRepository(feedUrl);

 

            string packagedir = string.Empty;
            PackageManager manager = null;

 

            manager.InstallPackage(packageId);

 

            PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(repo, outputPath);
            Console.WriteLine("before dl pkg");
            packageManager.InstallPackage(packageID);
        }
```

Comment: [The NuGet.org page for `NuGet.Core` says](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Core) the replacement is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk - may I ask why you didn't notice the big orange announcement posted there?

Comment: What does the code have to do with the question? Did you try to install the alternative specified in NuGet itself? Does the code compile? This sounds like a very lazy question, unless you really wanted to ask something else

Comment: `i am not able to install my own nuget packages` you don't need NuGet.Core to install packages from any source, including folders

Comment: I am trying to install the package at runtime

Comment: If you are using Baget only it has its own library you can use and has an example on how to download a NuGet package - https://loic-sharma.github.io/BaGet/advanced/sdk/#download-a-package